# oracle 11g pivot query optimization - multiple rows to single row

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot-table, sql-optimization, sql-tuning

I have below tables

```
user table
USER_ID    USER_NAME
1          smith
2          clark
3          scott
4          chris
5          john

property table
P_ID    PROPERTY
1       first_name
2       last_name
3       age
4       skill

user_property table
PV_ID    USER_ID    P_ID VALUE
1        1          1    Smith
2        1          2    A
3        1          3    34
4        1          4    Java
5        1          4    DB
6        2          1    Clark
7        2          2    B
8        2          3    39
9        2          4    Java
10       2          4    net
11       2          4    linux
12       3          1    Scott
13       3          2    C
14       3          3    31
```

I want to write a query which will fetch data from all above tables as below:(Skill will be first skill for that user if available otherwise null)

```
USER_ID USER_NAME FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME SKILL
1       smith     Smith      A         Java
2       clark     Clark      B         Java
3       scott     Scott      C         null
```

I have tried like below but  getting performance issue:

```
SELECT
  u.user_id,
  u.user_name,
  MAX(DECODE(p.property, 'first_name', text_value)) firstName,
  MAX(DECODE(p.property, 'last_name', text_value)) lastName,
  MAX(DECODE(p.property, 'age', text_value)) age,
  MAX(DECODE(p.property, 'skill', text_value)) skill
FROM user u,
  property p,
  user_property up,
WHERE u.user_id    = up.user_id
AND p.p_id = up.p_id
GROUP BY u.user_id,
  u.user_name;
```

How could i write this as optimized query for oracle 11g.

Comment: So how many rows do you have in each table?

Answer (score 0):

The performance of your query depends on the size of the table and on the indexes you have on these tables. It most cases, it is best practice to have an index on each primary and foreign key. The index on the primary key is a must anyway. The index on the foreign key speeds up joins and prevents table locks when you delete rows.

An alternative to your query would be to use more joins instead of subselects and to use the WITH clause to simplify it:

```
with t as (
  select u.user_id, u.user_name, up.p_id, up.value
  from user_property up
  join user u on u.user_id = up.user_id
)
select u.user_id, u.user_name,
    t_first_name.value first_name,
    t_last_name.value last_name,
    (select min(value) from t where t.user_id = u.user_id and t.p_id = 4) skill
from user u
left join t t_first_name on t_first_name.user_id = u.user_id and t_first_name.p_id = 1
left join t t_last_name on t_last_name.user_id = u.user_id and t_last_name.p_id = 2;
```

BTW: It's a data model which isn't well suited for SQL. I hope these user properties are the exception and the rest of the database has a cleaner design.

Comment: property table has 286 records , user table has 115838 records and user_property has 3221472  records. All tables have indexes on PK.

Comment: **property table has 286 records** (in this we are interested in around 45 properties, means 45 columns in output select clause), user table has 115838 records and user_property has 3221472  records. All tables have indexes on PK. Also min/max may impact on performance as we have around 45 columns

Comment: Do you want the final output to include a row for each of the 115,838 users? Or are you interested in a subset of the users?

Comment: No final row ill include only certain users having status active and registered to particular site. So i have addition where clause on internal select clause. Final user list be around 500 rows. I tried query given by you but giving me error as   ORA-00904: "t_first_name"."user_id": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Comment: I have modified my answer and hopefully fixed the query. As for the indexes: The most important one is to have a single index on USER_ID and P_ID of the table USER_PROPERTY. It might even be better to convert the table into an index organized table with these two attributes as the primary key. In addition, I recommend indexes that help efficiently select the 500 users you want to display.

Comment: Torino pls find details i have added in my new answer

Comment: Thanks for updates. Its working Working. Howerver origical query is taking 154 seconds and this new query is taking 130 seconds to execute.

Answer (score -1):

I have tried below query however getting Cartesian product.

```
with t as (
select u.user_id, u.user_name, up.p_id, up.value
from user_property up
join user u on u.user_id = up.user_id
where u.user_name = 'smith'
)
select u.user_id, u.user_name,
t_first_name.value first_name,
t_last_name.value last_name,
(select min(value) from t where t.user_id = u.user_id and t.p_id = 4) skill
from user u
left join t t_first_name on t_first_name.user_id = u.user_id and t_first_name.p_id = 1
left join t t_last_name on t_last_name.user_id = u.user_id and t_last_name.p_id = 2;
```

if i execute below query i get 5 as mentioned in my above example (As there are 5 rows in my user_property table for user_id 1 in example)

```
select count(u.user_id)
from user_property up
join user u on u.user_id = up.user_id
where u.user_name = 'smith'
```

Hence if i execute below query i get count as 3 as there are 3 rows in my use table example

```
with t as (
select u.user_id, u.user_name, up.p_id, up.value
from user_property up
join user u on u.user_id = up.user_id
where u.user_name = 'smith'
)
select count(u.user_id)
from user u
left join t t_first_name on t_first_name.user_id = u.user_id and t_first_name.p_id = 1
left join t t_last_name on t_last_name.user_id = u.user_id and t_last_name.p_id = 2;
```

Comment: Why have you added this as an answer and not updated your original question? Is there a minimum reputation required to edit one's own question?

Comment: I don't understand why you get a cartesian product. My query is correct: see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3495e/3).

Comment: @Torino: Thanks for updates. Its working Working. Howerver origical query is taking 145 seconds and this new query is taking 130 seconds to execute.